# Docker: TCP/IP connections on port 5342? connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host

Tags: docker, ruby-on-rails-7, ruby-3

I am using rails 3.0.0 with rails 7.

My dockerfile is as:

```
FROM ruby:3.0.0-alpine

RUN apk add --update --virtual \
    runtime-deps \
    postgresql-client\
    build-base \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    yarn \
    libffi-dev \
    readline \
    build-base \
    postgresql-dev \
    libc-dev \
    linux-headers \
    readline-dev \
    file \
    imagemagick \
    git \
    tzdata \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk*

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/
ENV BUNDLE_PATH /gems
RUN yarn install
RUN bundle install

ENTRYPOINT ["bin/rails"]
CMD ["s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-compose.yml is as:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - "dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@db:5433/postgres
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6380
    volumes:
      - .:/app

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

database.yml file is as:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  port: 5432

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_development
  username: postgres
  password: password

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_test

#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV["MY_APP_DATABASE_URL"] %>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_production
  username: my_app
  password: <%= ENV["MY_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>
```

using ubunut 20.04 LTS.
getting error as:
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "172.22.0.3" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5433?

How to resolve this issue, any suggestion would help, thanks in advance.

Comment: `DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@db:5432/postgres` The port you are publishing here `- "5433:5432"` is toward your host, not inside the docker network

Comment: Looks like you could also go `command: -p 5433` in the `db` container: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/196#issuecomment-310209118

Comment: No need to (also see my reply below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71833209/docker-tcp-ip-connections-on-port-5342-connect-to-server-connection-refused-i/71833367#comment126949644_71833549 

If you change the connection-string for the web service to connect to port `5432` (the port the container is listening on) it should be able to connect (`DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@db:5432/postgres`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

reached to solution from above shared suggestions:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
 version: '3.8'
    services:
      db:
        image: postgres:latest
        environment:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
          command: -p 5000
          ports: "5000:5432"
        volumes:
          - "dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    
      redis:
        image: redis:latest
        ports:
          - "6380:6379"
    
      web:
        build: .
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
        depends_on:
          - db
          - redis
        environment:
          - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@db:5432/postgres
          - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
        volumes:
          - .:/app
    
    volumes:
      dbdata:
```

**database.yml:**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_development
  username: postgres
  password: password

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_test

#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV["MY_APP_DATABASE_URL"] %>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_production
  username: my_app
  password: <%= ENV["MY_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ruby:3.0.0-alpine

RUN apk add --update --virtual \
    runtime-deps \
    postgresql-client\
    build-base \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    yarn \
    libffi-dev \
    readline \
    build-base \
    postgresql-dev \
    libc-dev \
    linux-headers \
    readline-dev \
    file \
    imagemagick \
    git \
    tzdata \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk*

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/
ENV BUNDLE_PATH /gems
RUN yarn install
RUN bundle install

ENTRYPOINT ["bin/rails"]
CMD ["s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

Now with these configurations rails app is running.
please update how to do it better, thanks.

Comment: What have you done that's different from the setup in the question?

Comment: added lines command: -p 5000, updates ports and  updated DATABASE_URL. @DavidMaze.

Comment: The compose file is now incorrect, as it's trying to map port `5432` of the container to port `5000` on the host, and the `-p 5000` changes the container itself to be listening on port `5000`, so it's no longer listening on port `5432`

Comment: It may be incorrect but working, please share you suggestion. @thaJeztah.

Answer (score 2):

Your `web` service is connecting with the `db` (postgresql) service using the internal docker network; when doing so, it connects directly to the IP address of the container, which (for postgresql) is listening on port `5432`. Connections over the docker network does not require ports to be published / exposed, so the `5433:5432` port-mapping is not used for that.

I should add that your compose file is publishing (port-mapping) both the `db` and `redis` services; publishing them means that they'll be publicly accessible on the host's network interface (which, if you're not on an internal network, **may be publicly accessible on the internet**).

Make sure to *only* publish ports for services that must be publicly accessible (or are protected through other ways); as described above, connections between containers / services does *not* require those ports to be published.